# login to web page using credentials from mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webview, firebase-authentication

I'm in the planning phase of my next project, and i have the following app that i would like to do the following:

It's a mobile app that the user will signup and into with Google Firebase Authentication. In the app theres a button that when pressed will open an embedded web-view of a site that i will have. When this page opens, i want the user to be automatically logged into this website.

Since i'll be using Firebase authentication, is there a way to somehow use the current user session's credential on the app, to access the webpage?